# Protected Restriction

Tags: protected-macro, function

Have seen

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \feuds_newteorema_define:nn
```

Is this just a definition of a function named `\feuds_newteorema_define` (taking two arguments as far as I can tell), Or is it something else ?

What does it mean exactly by `Protected Restriction` ?

Comment: `\cs_new_protected:Nn` defines a `\protected` macro, take a look at the e-TeX manual what that means (it basically means that the macro doesn't expand in an `\edef` context, stops the scanning for `\noalign` or `\omit` in an alignment, doesn't expand inside a `\write`)

Comment: are you user Veak?, you can ask stackexchange to merge the accounts if they are separated by accident.

Comment: @Skillmon I guess that's an answer (I couldn't see any obvious duplicate, surprisingly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short theory

`\cs_new_protected:Nn` is documented in the `interface3.pdf` and states that a function defined with it doesn't expand any further inside of an `x` or `e` type expansion.

What this means at the lower level is, that it uses the e-TeX primitive `\protected`. You can see what that means in the e-TeX manual (`texdoc etex`). But to summarise:

A macro defined `\protected`

- doesn't expand in an `\edef` or `\expanded` context
- doesn't expand in a `\write` or `\message` context
- stops TeX's scanning for `\omit` or `\noalign` inside of an alignment context (like a `\relax` would)

### Simple examples

An example showcasing the different behaviour (in plain TeX):

```
\protected\def\foo{protected }
\def\bar{unprotected}
\edef\baz{\foo\bar}
\show\baz
\bye
```

Results in the following output to stdout:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.8.16)  29 SEP 2023 12:21
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**document
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-11>
> \baz=macro:
->\foo unprotected.
l.4 \show\baz
             
?
```

As you can see `\bar` was expanded (to the word "unprotected"), but `\foo` wasn't and remains as `\foo` inside of `\baz`'s replacement text.

---

Another example using the L3 syntax and printing into the PDF:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \test_foo: { foo }
\cs_new:Nn \test_bar: { bar }

\cs_new:Nx \test_baz: { \test_foo: \test_bar: }
\test_baz: \par

\cs_set_protected:Nn \test_foo: { FOO }
\cs_set:Nn \test_bar: { BAR }

\test_baz:
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, on the first usage of `\test_baz:` it printed "foobar" since both `\test_foo:` and `\test_bar:` were lowercase. If we alter that afterwards to both being uppercase this only results in "FOO" but "bar" remains lowercase. That's the case because when we defined `\test_baz:` we expanded `\test_bar:` to "bar", but `\test_foo:` wasn't expanded due to it being `protected`, so its redefinition also alters the result of `\test_baz:`.

---

### Why or when is this behaviour important?

In TeX we have the notion of things that are expandable, and things that aren't. Some primitives are expandable, but most aren't. Macros on the other hand are expandable (unless defined `\protected`, in which case they are only expandable by certain operations like `\expandafter`, but not in `\edef` or `\expanded`).

If a macro now uses one of the unexpandable primitives, but somehow ends up in an `\edef` or `\expanded` context and would expand itself you'd get undefined/unpredictable behaviour (because anything after your unexpandable primitives still gets expanded). Because of this, it is necessary to define such macros `\protected`, so that the behaviour (almost -- let's ignore the ways to still expand a `\protected` macro) always stays well defined.

Here is a small, hopefully easy to understand example of this (again in plain TeX syntax):

```
\def\mymacroA{\def\mythingA{foobar}}
\protected\def\mymacroB{\def\mythingB{foobar}}

\edef\test{\mymacroB}% this is still fine
\edef\test{\mymacroA}% this throws an error
\bye
```

This prints to stdout:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\mymacroA ->\def \mythingA 
                           {foobar}
l.5 \edef\test{\mymacroA
                        }% this throws an error
?
```

even though both `\mythingA` and `\mythingB` would be fine if used outside of `\edef`. The reason is quite simple: `\def` isn't expandable, so stays the same, but TeX continues to expand the rest of the replacement text of `\mymacroA` which hits `\mythingA`. That macro isn't expandable, so we get above error message.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how protected works out.  I find the answer too theoretical.

Comment: For the `L3 syntax`, do the  `x` or `e` type expansion have meaning ?  If the definition of protected is expressed  in terms of `x` or `e` type commands only, `\cs_new_protected:Nn` might skip the discussion for the `L3 Syntax` routines.

Comment: In general terms the `protected` marker means that the defined function is protected from expansion in certain contexts. Expansion is the process of replacing macros and control sequences with their actual values or definitions. However, there are situations where this expansion is not desired, especially in places where LaTeX processes content in a different way, such as section headings.  Do the manuals give such discussion regarding the need for expansion protection for section headings ?

Comment: @Fluffy `x` is `\edef` expansion, `e` is `\expanded` expansion. It means that the macro will as argument not get literally what was given, but the result of either `\edef` or `\expanded` on that argument. I don't understand what you mean with "... might skip the discussion for the `L3 Syntax` routines".

Comment: @Fluffy yes, in LaTeX2e you got the `\protect` macro to use in headings and stuff (moving arguments is the term) to prevent things from expanding, a mechanism that predates e-TeX and the `\protected` primitive. See the LaTeX companion.